# MediaPlayer is stopping the sound when activity goes to background

Tags: android, audio, media-player

**[EDITED]** My app is basically a `listview` that each row (position) play a sound that is playing in loop until the same position is pressed again.

I create each sound by `MediaPlayer.create()` and stop all of them on `onDestroy()` of activity (in order to if the activity is destroyed - by pressing back button for instance, all  sounds be sttoped).

The problem is: this works very well (I tried for 5 hours continously) on a device with API 16. But on my other device (tablet API 22) when the home button is pressed the sound is immediately turned off, however the same does not occurred on emulator with API 22 also.

Now I'm insecure about my app. I don't know if my app is wrong, if the emulator is or if my device is. :( Anyone already had the same behavior with sounds on app? Anyone knows if has any configuration on tablet with API 22 that can produce this behavior? And mostly how I fix this?

**NOTE** - I don't want to use service 'cause like I said that way was working well and with service I had some problems with index of my array that store the positions already pressed.

Thanks

Comment: The last sentence isn't a question.

Comment: you can use service instead. try this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/UsingServicetoplaymediafile.htm also consult the docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Comment: @Akash Raghav  My questions was not clear, then I edited it. If you could take a look again on it, I'll thankful.

Comment: please add your code as well. so that we can try something out to rectify the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Akash Raghav , but the problem wasn't on code it was on how my tablet was setted, I had checked the option don't keep activities on developer options, this way my activities always call onDestroy() in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many hours struggling with this stupid question and wondering why my tablet had a behavior different of emulator, I finally found the answer, a simple answer.

My tablet was setted to `don't keep activities` on `developer options`, then when the home button was pressed the activity was destroyed and all sounds turned off. It was just uncheck this option and now everything works.

If anyone have the same problem can be this.